# Hide duplicate content from the database in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a retweet/repin feature for my app. How should I go about hiding the duplicate 'content' in the view? I have it setup in the index view so that it shows all the entries from the table `<%= render @letsgos %>`.

I setup the retweet/repin so that User B can repost what User A posted. In the database it will copy the original posting from User A, and in the column 'repost_from_user_id' it will show the original id of the 'content'.

controller:

```
class LetsgosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy

  def create
    @letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build(letsgo_params)
    if @letsgo.save
      flash[:success] = "Date posted!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Date was not posted!"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @letsgo.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def index
    @letsgos = Letsgo.all 
    @eat = Letsgo.where(:tag => 'Eat')
  end

  def eatdrink
    @eatdrink = Letsgo.where(:tag => 'Eat/Drink')
  end

  def listenwatch
    @listenwatch = Letsgo.where(:tag => 'Listen/Watch')
  end

  def play
    @play = Letsgo.where(:tag => 'Play')
  end

  def explore
    @explore = Letsgo.where(:tag => 'Explore')
  end

  def other
    @other = Letsgo.where(:tag => 'Other')
  end

  def repost
    @letsgo = Letsgo.find(params[:id]).repost(current_user)
    redirect_to root_url
  end

private

  def letsgo_params
    params.require(:letsgo).permit(:content, :tag)
  end

  def correct_user
    @letsgo = current_user.letsgos.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @letsgo.nil?
  end
end
```

model:

```
class Letsgo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 360 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  def repost(user_object)
    new_letsgo = self.dup #duplicates the entire object, except for the ID
    new_letsgo.user_id = user_object.id
    new_letsgo.repost_from_user_id = self.id #save the user id of original repost, to keep track of where it originally came from
    new_letsgo.save
  end

  def is_repost?
    repost_from_user_id.present?
  end

  def original_user
    User.find(repost_from_user_id) if is_repost?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you do not want to show the reposts (or the originals). You should use a scope or where method in your index.
So instead of:

```
def index
  @letsgos = Letsgo.all 
  @eat = Letsgo.where(:tag => 'Eat')
end
```

try:

```
def index
  @letsgos = Letsgo.where("repost_from_user_id IS NULL").all 
  @eat = Letsgo.where(:tag => 'Eat')
end
```

This should only show the originals. Showing only the reposts is a harder because it isn't as easy to filter them out. You might have to add a column to your model to flag the original when it was reposted. something like:

```
self.reposted = true
self.save
```

in your repost method.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote something similar to that but not exactly. That answer was pretty basic so I should've came to that conclusion. Thanks for the help!! I only needed to show the original. You were of great assistance